# iMacros TAG field input cannot detect HTML field

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, moodle, imacros

I am writing an iMacros script that will post data in a Moodle Lesson.

I am trying to paste content in the description field using TAG, but it doesn't recognize the field:

```
<div id="fitem_id_introeditor" class="fitem fitem_feditor "><div class="fitemtitle"><label for="id_introeditor">Description </label></div><div class="felement feditor"><div><div><textarea id="id_introeditor" name="introeditor[text]" rows="10" cols="80" spellcheck="true"></textarea></div><div><input name="introeditor[format]" type="hidden" value="1" /></div><input type="hidden" name="introeditor[itemid]" value="149225125" /><noscript><div><object type='text/html' data='http://domain.com/moodle29/repository/draftfiles_manager.php?action=browse&amp;env=editor&amp;itemid=149225125&amp;subdirs=1&amp;maxbytes=0&amp;areamaxbytes=-1&amp;maxfiles=-1&amp;ctx_id=35&amp;course=4&amp;sesskey=0cvoTuPGNP' height='160' width='600' style='border:1px solid #000'></object></div></noscript></div></div></div>
```

I have so far tried to use these:

```
'TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:id_introeditoreditable CONTENT="test"

'TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:id_introeditoreditable CONTENT="test"

'TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=ID:yui_3_17_2_2_1445343121435_1492 CONTENT="test"

'TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEST/HTML ATTR=ID:id_introeditor CONTENT="test"
```

But none of the above actually catches the field to paste in it.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Try to use 'Experimental event recording mode'. (The 'Record options' button -> Recording preferences window.) This way likely will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard for me to help without seeing the field itself.

But maybe you can try:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:id_introeditor CONTENT="test"

or try getting rid of the attr:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT CONTENT="test"

If you can show us the link with the specific field, it'll be easier for us to help!